# Do I have the right idea for my Multidimensional array search in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, xna

I'm new to Multidimensional arrays and just want to make sure I have the right idea for the search before start to code against it later today.

```
        public int[,] LocationXY = new int[5,5];
```

**Edit Array Search For Multi-dimensional Arrays:**

Would the pseudocode for searching a multidimensional array of 5 by 5 be something like this?

The XNA code for moving the map:

```
            background.direction.X = background.position.X + 3000;
            background.direction.Normalize();
            background.position.X += background.direction.X *               
            ball.speed;
            backgroundWest.direction.X = backgroundWest.position.X + 3000;
            backgroundWest.direction.Normalize();
            backgroundWest.position.X += background.direction.X * ball.speed;
            Map.ArraySearch(XSearch, YSearch);

            //if statement for changing background sprite.  
            if(LocationXY[0,1])
              background01.LoadContent(this.content, "background01";
```

The Search Function:

```
public int [,] ArraySearch(XSearch, YSearch)  

  {  
            for(int X = 0; X < XSearch; X++)  
                for(int Y = 0; Y < YSearch; Y++)  
                   if(Y == YSearch && X == XSearch)
                    return LocationXY[XSearch, YSearch]  
       }
```

The general idea is grabbing the array value for the if statement the background sits under.  I wish switch statements could take multidimensional arrays.

Comment: The best way to find out - try it. Play with it. See what is happening. A short simple program to compile and test inputs, outputs and debug through will teach you much more than someone giving you an answer here.

Comment: Your code looks technically correct but certainly isn't the best or easiest way to register X,Y coordinates. Consider a `List<MyPoint>`.

Comment: @Oded No. The best way to learn is no play around, but methodically exploring what you can do, how and why. That starts from understanding the fundamental concepts, and continues in the documentation. not reverse engineering C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go to the MSDN and read about [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx), [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), and [jagged arrays.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

What you are doing in the code in your answer is kind of strange... the loops and the way you are returning the values contradict.

assuming an array `int[,] a = new int[X,Y]` ( the size does not matter),

This would get the cell at index m,n:

```
int value = a[m,n]
```

This will search the array for a the location of a cell that has the value five:

```
Tuple<int,int> search (int[,] arr, int value)
{
    for(int i=0; i < arr.GetLength(0);i++ )
        for(int j=0; j < arr.GetLength(1);j++)
            if(arr[i,j] == value)
                return Tuple.Create(i,j);
}
```

Comment: Would the syntax for the switch statement be `switch(Map.TupleHolder.Item1)`  
  `case 0;`
     `switch (Map.TupleHolder.Item2)`
       `case:0`

Comment: no... 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: That syntax works for picking out the right image for X and Y coordinate switches.

Comment: I was just checking I understood parts of the tuple syntax.  Isn't the point of this service improving coding skills?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a matrix, use: `int[,]`

If you want an array of array, in where all sub array can have a different length, use: `int[][]`. Remember (besides creating the main array) to always create a subarray before filling it, otherwise you get a NullReferenceException.

If you want a  list of X and Y coordinates, use: `Point[]`.

Comment: Would the pseudocode for searching a multidimensional array of 5 by 5 be something like this?  
  

 `public int [,] ArraySearch(XSearch, YSearch)  
         
  {  
            for(int X = 0; X < XSearch; X++)  
                for(int Y = 0; Y < YSearch; Y++)  
                   return LocationXY[XSearch, YSearch]  
       }`

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Your code just returns the first element of the first row, thus: `LocationXY[0,0]`.

Comment: So, I just need to wrap the `return` with an `if(Y == YSearch)` to grab the specific coordinates?

Comment: I still do not understand. Can you give me an read life example, perhapse editing your question? Like: I have this (piece of code with data) and I want this result (a piece of data).

Comment: I'm trying to grab coordinates as a player moves through a map divided into 25 separate sprite backgrounds.  When he transitions to a new area the current map slides out and the new one slides in based on the values of the old and new map.   I can't use Point[] for it since the class library is supposed to be independent of the view.